# if statement doesn't work in while loop with time lib python

Tags: python, if-statement, time, while-loop

Here is the code (only this):

```
import pytz
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime

dt_format = "%H:%M" 
tz = pytz.timezone('Asia/Riyadh')
jt = datetime.now(tz)
time_now = (jt.strftime(dt_format))
time = time_now.replace(":","")
timed1 = (int("1530")) #the time in 24h format


while True:
    #print('azan on')

    if timed1 == time_now:
        print(time_now)
        print(timed1)
        print ("its the time")
        sleep (90)
```

I tried to keep the format normal (15:30) but still the same.

(replace) not required you can delete if so.

Comment: `timed1` is an integer (i.e. the number 1530, while `time_now` is a string (`15:30`) - they'll never be identical. You're not updating the value of `time_now` inside your `while` loop either, so the values would never change (.. if they even compared as they should).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks Bro! Its working now after updating time and put it in the loop .

Answer (score 0):

You just have to update the time and put it in the loop and it will work , thanks to @MatsLindh (check comments)